# Java jfilechooser using FileNameFilter

Tags: java

I cant get jfilechooser to show the files I return from FileNameFilter. It still shows me all the files inside the folder. I believe fileChooser.setSelectedFiles(listOfMatchingFiles); should set what contents are displayed. I've searched the net but have only found examples of how to set what type of file extensions are viewable. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
    final String[] currSelection = selecName.split("_");

    FilenameFilter fileNames = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.startsWith(currSelection[0])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };


            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

            File[] listOfMatchingFiles = fileLOcation.listFiles(fileNames);

            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(fileLOcation);

            fileChooser.setSelectedFiles(listOfMatchingFiles);


            for (File a : listOfMatchingFiles) {
          //displays the set of files according to currSelection[0]
          System.out.println(a);
            }

            fileChooser.setDialogTitle(currSelection[0]);

            if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File fileToVIEW = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

}

Comment: `setSelectedFiles()`, as the name implies, sets the selected files. `setFileFilter()` is what you are looking for...

Comment: @PeterSmith

when I try fileChooser.setFileFilter(fileNames);

it asks me to cast it to

fileChooser.setFileFilter((FileFilter) fileNames);

and throws an error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: my.Program cannot be cast to javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter

Ive only seen setFileFilter used for file extensions

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?